# Add Data Synchronization Module in Magnolia CMS Community?

Tags: module, synchronization, magnolia

I am trying to add the Data Synchronization Module to a Magnolia CMS 5.0 Community instance, but as far as I have investigated, this is only possible for Enterprise editions. Am I wrong? If anyone could provide me with a good tutorial of how to do so, it will be enough, and I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this module is enterprise only. OTOH since you have only one public with community edition, what would you need to synchronize with?

Comment: Thanks for replying Jan! I will need to work in that instance with some other developers, and we have to be able to see the changes made by each of us. I found out about dx-sync-module, which is aimed to work on community editions. However, I haven't been able to implement it as it has very brief documentation.